# What does "#ffff##:0" mean in xauth?

Tags: fedora, xauth

(Migrated from ServerFault.SE)

I'm working on a Silverblue system, in part via SSH with X11 forwarding.

When I use the graphical console and say `xauth list` I get this:

```
silverblue/unix:0   MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 <token1>
#ffff##:0   MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 <token1>
```

`$XAUTHORITY = /run/user/1000/xauth_dkafiw`

so this is obviously something set up by Silverblue specially.

But when I log in via `ssh -X` I get `xauth list` of

```
silverblue/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  <token2>
silverblue/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  <token3>
```

I think the mysterious line in the console xauth is to make `toolbox` work with X. I can say `toolbox enter` and start an X11 program from the command line, and it works. But if I try that in `ssh` it doesn't. This seems to be because `toolbox` sets the `hostname` to "toolbox", so if I say `xauth add toolbox/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 <token3>`  it starts working again (or `sudo hostname silverblue` inside the toolbox also works).

So my questions:

- What does `#ffff##:0` mean in `xauth list`? Am I right about it solving the toolbox issue?
- How do I get it in there? Using `xauth add` tells me it's an invalid address.